# avconv: How to blur scenes?

Tags: video, libav

I want to blur some scenes with avconv
The ffmpeg command -find it [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/how-to-blur-a-short-scene-in-a-video)- is:

> ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf "boxblur=enable='between(t,22,113)'" -codec:a copy output.avi

doesn't work with avconv

> avconv -i "video_in" -vf "boxblur=10:1" "video_out"

blur the whole video, what can I add to it to blur selected scenes. 
Thanks

Comment: last progress: `avconv -i "video_in" -vf "select='gte(t,10)*lte(t,20)', boxblur=10:1" "video_out"` but I lose lte 10 and gte 20 black screen `avconv -i "video_in" -vf "select='lte(t,10)'" "select='gte(t,10)*lte(t,20)', boxblur=10:1" "select='gte(t,20)'" "video_out"` doesn't work...

Comment: last progress:`avconv -i 01.mpg -filter_complex "[0:v]select='lte(t,10)' , copy[out1] ; [0:v]select='gte(t,10)*lte(t,20)' , boxblur=10:1[out2] ;[0:v] select='gte(t,20)' , copy[out3]"....` all what I want is in [OUT1] [OUT2] [OUT3] someone can help me to put it in one -"OUT.mpg"- file